# How do I send our assault squads in Metal Gear Solid: Phantom Pain?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

I blinked and missed a scene where there was a reference to being able to send out squads into the wild to carry out missions, gather intel, etc.

There were no changes to the menu, so I carried on and completed another mission, and some side missions. I returned to base, again, but still nothing.  Developed the base a bit further, but still no option to send these squads out.

I found a reference in an online guide that mentions sending these guys out quite often, and that a new screen will be present next to the missions.

Have I screwed something up?  When does that become available and/or what triggers it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it turns out I hadn't done enough of the main missions to unlock the combat platform.

The option to add a combat platform opened up for me after I completed mission 9, possibly 10. It was the one where you had to take out the three tanks.

I had already built the medical bay but don't think this had anything to do with it. 
Looks like the platforms unlock in order, so possibly after 7 missions complete you unlock the medbay and then after 10 the combat platform. 
Once unlocked the option to send out troops is very clear to see

Comment: You may want to add a bit more information to this answer, like what you had done, and what needed to be completed to unlock the platform. Currently this is a very low quality answer.

Comment: Simply put-do more missions. :) there wasn't anything else as a requirement. I'll add the mission number

Answer (score 0):

After completing a certain number of main story operations, Miller will inform you about the ability to form combat teams.  This includes the ability to build combat platforms at your home base.  When you access the base menu after this, you should be prompted with a tutorial that tells you about how teams are formed and another on the missions tab that walks you through sending out a combat team on a mission.

Comment: Informative, but this does not appear to answer the question. OP is asking why none of this shows up, not for an explanation on what should happen.

Comment: @Timelord64 The actual question states if he's either messed something up or what triggers it.  Which I have described.

Comment: Good point. That said, OP appears to have already taken the actions you detail to trigger. So while informative, this does not answer the primary issue, in that its not actually triggering. There is no real point for partial answers, here.

Comment: You send them out on missions via the Missions tab, not the Mother Base tab. It's unclear where exactly @SteveGreen is looking for this option.